# $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}, dimV<\infty$. $T:V \to V $ .Prove that exist T-invariant subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $P_{T|W}=m_{T|W}=m_T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}, dimV<\infty$.

$T:V \to V $ is a linear trasnformation.

Prove that exist T-invariant subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $P_{T|W}=m_{T|W}=m_T$.

Lets say $P_T$ is not a product of linear factors over $\mathbb F$ then there is no similarity Jordan matrix, how am I suppose to prove the existence of $W$ ?

Lets say $P_T$ is a product of linear factors over $\mathbb F$:

Suppose $P_T$ is a irreducible polynomial, then $P_T=m_T$  since $m_T|P_T \implies P_{T|W}=m_{T|W}=m_T$.

Suppose $P_T$ is a reducible polynomial and $P_T\neq m_T$  then $m_T|P_T$.

Lets suppose exist $k$ different eigenvalues
then

$P_T=\prod_{i=1}^k(x-\lambda_i)^{a_i}$, $m_T=\prod_{j=1}^k(x-\lambda_j)^{b_j}$. ($\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, $b_{i}\leq a_{i}$).

Define $W=V_{\lambda_{1}}\oplus V_{\lambda_{2}}\oplus\cdots V_{\lambda_{k}}$

$W$ is T-invariant since each $V_{\lambda_{i}}$ is a T-invariant.

Here I get stuck I don't get how $m_T=m_T|W$.

I will be grateful for some help !

Comment: What's is $m_T$? $P_T$?

Comment: Minimal polynomial

Comment: "First of all, I don't get why I just can't take $V=W$ and that's it." So you're saying that we always have the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial equal? You already showed that you understand that that is not so.

Comment: @TedShifrin I forget it after some minutes, and forget to remove it. Edit

Comment: You should be concentrating on whether $P_{T|W} = m_{T|W}$.

Comment: $W := <V_1>\oplus<V_2>\cdots<V_j>$ when $V_1\cdots V_j $ are the vectors that create the maximal jordan chain of each eigenvalue? Then I know $P_{T|W} = m_{T|W}$ am i wrong ?